# How to delay an animated sprite in Andengine?

Tags: delay, andengine, animated

I have an animated Sprite that is drawn on the screen when I press the button. However, I want to the animation to start after 5 seconds. Technically, the ver first PNG in the "animation set" is shown and the animation starts after 5 seconds.

I have tried to used the `DelayModifier` as follows, but without luck:

```
mySprite.registerEntityModifier(new DelayModifier(500)); //doesn't work
```

I would appreciate your input.

Comment: True, the DelayModifier didn't actually work, whatever value you passed to it. 500 there was just a random test value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem from this tutorial: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/using-timer-s-sprite-spawn-example-t463.html

The idea was to use a TimeHandler and not a DelayModifier.

Answer (score 0):

actually , you can do it with a delaymodifier too , like this

```
DelayModifier dMod = new DelayModifier(5f){
    @override
    public void onModifierFinished(IModifier arg0, IEntity arg1) {
        mySprite.animate(300);
    }
}
mySprite.registerEntityModifier(dMod);
```